# MySQL - Making other columns a function of the auto-increment column

Tags: php, mysql

This question has been asked but never clearly answered (as far as I am aware): -
I want to give my users a unique temporary username. My idea is to make their username a function of the id column as follows: -

```
id username
  1 user1
  2 user2
  . . . 
  967 user967
  968 user968
```

I can do this with an INSERT, a SELECT and an UPDATE, but is there a more efficient way? Can it be done with just an INSERT?

Comment: better to use temporary slug. and an update

Comment: Thanks - judging by the lack of replies I don't think there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

First you need to read current `AUTO_INCREMENT` value *to be assigned* and use it to generate the temporary username.

**Example**:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_bi_tbl_name //

CREATE TRIGGER trg_bi_tbl_name
       BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_name
       FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE _user_id INT DEFAULT 0;

    IF NEW.username IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH( TRIM( NEW.username ) ) = 0 THEN
         SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT INTO _user_id
           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_name'
            AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();

         SET NEW.username = CONCAT( 'user', _user_id );
    END IF;
END;

//

DELIMITER ;
```

As you mentioned it is for temporary username suggestion, I don't think you need a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

Comment: Many thanks. Quite complicated, and so I conclude it's probably simpler to do it with a couple of calls from php.